# can't get data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve `data-cost("#packages")` and append it to `#form` next to `Ticket-price`. I am not getting any errors in console. I can't seen to understand what went wrong.

JS:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
        var price=$("#packages").data("cost");
        var amount=$("<span>"+price+"</span>");
        $("#form").next().next().append(amount);

    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="packages">
    <h2><u>Tourism Packages:</u></h2>
     <ul>
        <li data-name="Southern Travels">Travels Name:  Southern Travels</li>
        <li data-cost="2000">Cost per person:  2000</li>
        <li>Duration:  3 days & 4 nights</li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div id="form">
    <label>Number of persons </label>
    <input id="input"type="text"/ autofocus>
    <p id="ticket-price">Ticket Price</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Targeting 2nd li element inside #packages
    var price=$("#packages li").eq(2).data("cost");

    // create a span element with text 'price'
    var amount=$("<span>"+price+"</span>");

    // append as last child of the form
    $("#form").append(amount);
});
```

Comment: This is not a flexible solution since you are specifically stating to look at the 2nd li - if he adds another li above it - this breaks - that's bad.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work as it is, you must edit your HTML as following:

```
<div id="packages" data-name="Southern Travels" data-cost="2000">
    <h2><u>Tourism Packages:</u></h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Travels Name:  Southern Travels</li>
        <li>Cost per person:  2000</li>
        <li>Duration:  3 days & 4 nights</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Either that, or access the data properties of the `<li>` elements instead of the `div#packages` (i.e `#packages ul li` instead of `#packages`)

Comment: The other problem is that `$("#form").next().next().append` will not append it next to `#ticket-price`...

Comment: Hi, modified my code to above recommendations(both) .but still the problem persists.

Comment: @user3484925: If you did *both* of my solutions it won't work because they exclude each other. You must *either* change the HTML *or* change the jQuery selector.

Comment: implemented in two different scenarios.but, i found the solution i am lookin for.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for your data attribute by name - and look at the LI's.

You also need to build your html string and append it properly to the #ticket-price

**WOKING EXAMPLE (FIDDLE)**: http://jsfiddle.net/ojLo8ojz/

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var price = $("#packages li[data-cost]").attr("data-cost");
        var amount = "<span> "+price+"</span>";
        $("#ticket-price").append(amount);
    });
```